# US Keyboard in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, keyboard-layout

my keyboard keeps reverting to US layout, even though I've deleted it and there's only UK keyboard in settings.  This has only happened since saucy salamander. has any body got any advice? It's a Dell Latitude XT3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also noticed this, I'm unsure as to why it happens but restarting **lightdm** will solve it.

Open Terminal, copy & paste the command:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Press **Enter**, then enter your password and finally press **Enter** again. Lightdm will be restarted and your keyboard will revert back to UK settings.

Comment: thanks @scouser73 That worked for me.. I could do with trying to stop it happening in the first place as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found this workaround: keep US keyboard installed aside the one you need, select "Show current input source in the menu bar" (under Settings/Text Entry). After login, use the input source icon displayed in the menu bar to switch once to US keyboard, then back to your required layout.