# Keyboard layout changes after reboot

Tags: keyboard-layout

Each time I reboot my system, the keyboard layout is falling back to US layout even though I want it to be in French layout. This is my default value and this is also the one that is ticked in the keyboard layout menu from the tray. I just need to click once again on the French icon for the layout to get it to work properly but this is quite annoying.

Did someone have the same problem and found a solution? It is apparently a non-unique case since there is already a bug report for this (see this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198)). I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Yep, same problem here. It appeared in Ubuntu 13.10 back in September, then it vanished and now it seems the bug is back, for me for about two weeks ... I was just trying to ask about the same thing :). Could you please put here a link to that bug? Thanks.

Comment: @zubozrout See my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works on my computer but which might not suit all the users...

I just removed the IBus package from the Software Centre and this works fine. After each reboot I now have my favorite layout!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend removing iBus. It changes a lot of other things too. E.g. a lot of items are missing in 'System Settings' ... (Appearance, Color, Display, ...) Had the same problem, the workaround of brunces helped for me too. Upvoted it.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem here, but I'm using this workaround:

Go to "System Settings > Text Entry". Under "Input sources to use", add your keyboard layout if it still doesn't exist, then move it to the top of all layouts you already have. Or, if you prefer, you can simply delete all the layouts you don't need and keep only the one you want (that's what I've done here).

Now, open the "Startup Applications", click on Add and do the following:

> Name: KeyLaySet (This is made up. Invent your own.)
>   Command: bash -c "sleep 5 && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0"
>   Comment: Sets keyboard layout to default

About Name:
You can use whatever you want.

About Command:
After the system starts up, it will wait for 5 seconds and then change the keyboard layout to the default one (that one you moved to the top in the "Input sources to use" box).

Click on "Save" and then "Close". Now, every time you start Ubuntu, your keyboard layout will be properly set.

I hope it's helpful. Cheers. :)

brunces

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the US layout? If you don't, you could try deleting it.

1. System Settings
2. Text Entry
3. Click on the US layout
4. Click the minus button

Comment: I don't use it regularly so I guess that could be a way to solve that. However it would be nice to get a real idea of what the problem is too!

Comment: Is the problem still there if you delete the US layout and reinstall it?

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I can do a reboot.

Comment: Yes the problem is still there after removing the US layout and reinstall it (as the third choice) and a reboot.

Comment: Hmm, it's worse than I thought (this solved it for me) ...

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on a French keyboard. Even if FR is enlighted in the menu, keyboard is EN, I must swich to FR to get FR keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Still guessing, in the Text Entry page, does the French layout appear above the US layout? If not, you could try putting it to the top with the up/down arrows and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Yes French layout is the first one of the list.

Answer (score 0):

[Another solution shared by scouser73 on another Ask](https://askubuntu.com/a/365186/216980) seems to solve the issue :

1. Open the terminal
2. sudo restart lightdm
3. Enter
4. Type your password
5. Enter

A word of caution .. `sudo restart lightdm` will restart your X-session, so make sure you've saved everything and/or quit everything first to avoid risk of losing data.

Comment: @Gordon, you will be able to comment as soon as you have [enough](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). Editing answers is allready possible, but will need to be reviewed and accepted from others as of right now.